# xquery or xslt to convert time hours to PT*H*M format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery

I am new to XQuery and XSLT.

I'm looking for an XQuery or XQuery function to convert the timetotal i.e. 5 Hours to `PT5H` or 5.5 hours to `PT5H30M`

Not sure if XQuery can do that. If not any XSLT 1.0 function is ok too.

Comment: can you provide a sample input? It's not clear what the value is that you are trying to convert to a duration formatted value. How would 5 hours or 5.5 hours be represented, or are you subtracting dateTimes, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define an `xs:dayTimeDuration` with a fractional number of hours, or minutes, but you *can* use a fractional number of seconds, so just multiply the hours by 3600 and create a duration in seconds:

```xml
xs:dayTimeDuration(
   concat(
      'PT', 
      $hours * 3600,
      'S'
   )
)
```

e.g.

```
let 
   $hours:= 5.551245
return
   xs:dayTimeDuration(
      concat(
         'PT', 
         $hours * 3600,
         'S'
      )
   )
```

returns: `PT5H33M4.482S`

Comment: NB this is pure XPath, so it's usable in XSLT or XQuery

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <hours>5</hours>
    <hours>5.5</hours>
    <hours>5.555</hours>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="hours">
            <xsl:variable name="seconds" select=". * 3600" />
            <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($seconds div 3600)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($seconds div 60) mod 60"/>
            <xsl:variable name="s" select="$seconds mod 60"/>
            <duration>
                <xsl:text>PT</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$h"/>
                <xsl:text>H</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$m"/>
                <xsl:text>M</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
                <xsl:text>S</xsl:text>
            </duration>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <duration>PT5H0M0S</duration>
   <duration>PT5H30M0S</duration>
   <duration>PT5H33M18S</duration>
</output>
```

This assumes the input value cannot be negative.

---

Do note that `PT5H30M`and `PT330M` are equally valid expressions of the same duration - so you could just multiply the input value by 60 (assuming you only need precision to a minute).

Comment: Thank you . i will try this xslt template. is that something can we used or done in xquery as well

Comment: I'm afraid don't know much about XQuery. Doesn't the other answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks Michael. This works for me. my  project has other xqueries so wanted to amke it consitent. But i think i will use xslt for this one. Thanks again

Comment: Is your question not answered?